# Efficently slicing non-integer multilevel indexes with integers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code generates a sample DataFrame with a multilevel index. The first level is a `string`, the second level is a `datetime`.

#### Script

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import random

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['network','time','active_clients','throughput','speed'])
networks = ['ALPHA','BETA','GAMMA']
times = pd.date_range(datetime.strptime('2021-01-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),datetime.strptime('2021-01-01 12:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),7).tolist()

for n in networks:
    for t in times:
        df = df.append({'network':n,'time':t,'active_clients':random.randint(10,30),'throughput':random.randint(1500,5000),'speed':random.randint(10000,12000)},ignore_index=True)

df.set_index(['network','time'],inplace=True)

print(df.to_string())
```

#### Output

```
                            active_clients throughput  speed
network time                                                
ALPHA   2021-01-01 00:00:00             16       4044  11023
        2021-01-01 02:00:00             17       2966  10933
        2021-01-01 04:00:00             10       4649  11981
        2021-01-01 06:00:00             23       3629  10113
        2021-01-01 08:00:00             30       2520  11159
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             10       4200  11309
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             16       3878  11366
BETA    2021-01-01 00:00:00             17       3073  11798
        2021-01-01 02:00:00             20       1941  10640
        2021-01-01 04:00:00             17       1980  11869
        2021-01-01 06:00:00             23       3346  10002
        2021-01-01 08:00:00             10       1952  10063
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             28       3788  11047
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             24       4993  10487
GAMMA   2021-01-01 00:00:00             21       4366  11587
        2021-01-01 02:00:00             22       3404  11669
        2021-01-01 04:00:00             20       1608  10344
        2021-01-01 06:00:00             28       1849  10278
        2021-01-01 08:00:00             14       3229  11925
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             21       3408  10411
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             12       1799  10492
```

For each item in the first level, I want to select the last three records in the second level. The catch is that I don't know the `datetime` values, **so I need to select by integer-based index location instead**. What's the most efficient way of slicing the DataFrame to achieve the following.

#### Desired output

```
                            active_clients throughput  speed
network time                                                
ALPHA   2021-01-01 08:00:00             30       2520  11159
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             10       4200  11309
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             16       3878  11366
BETA    2021-01-01 08:00:00             10       1952  10063
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             28       3788  11047
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             24       4993  10487
GAMMA   2021-01-01 08:00:00             14       3229  11925
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             21       3408  10411
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             12       1799  10492
```

#### My attempts

Returns the full dataframe:

```
df_sel = df.iloc[:,-3:]
```

Raises an error because `loc` doesn't support using integer values on `datetime` objects:

```
df_sel = df.loc[:,-3:]
```

Returns the last three entries in the second level, but only for the last entry in the first level:

```
df_sel = df.loc[:].iloc[-3:]
```

Comment: `df.groupby(level=0).tail(3)`?

Comment: Huh, i didn't know you pass level to groupby.

Comment: Thanks Quang, I didn't realise tail accepted any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 methods to solve this problem:

Method 1:
As it mentions from the first comment from Quang Hoang, you can use groupby to do this, which I believe has the shortest code:

```
df.groupby(level=0).tail(3)
```

Method 2:
You can also slice each one in networks then concat them:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[[i]][-3:] for i in networks])
```

Both of these 2 methods will output the result you want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to do some reshaping:

```
df.unstack(0).iloc[-3:].stack().swaplevel(0,1).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                            active_clients throughput  speed
network time                                                
ALPHA   2021-01-01 08:00:00             26       4081  11325
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             13       3370  10716
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             13       3691  10737
BETA    2021-01-01 08:00:00             28       2105  10465
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             21       2444  10158
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             24       1947  11226
GAMMA   2021-01-01 08:00:00             13       1850  10288
        2021-01-01 10:00:00             23       2241  11521
        2021-01-01 12:00:00             30       3515  11138
```

Details:

- `unstack` the outer most index level, level=0
- Use, `iloc` to select the last three records in the dataframe
- `stack` that level back to the index `swaplevel` and `sort_index`